# having trouble with PHP FPDF functions when using associative array

Tags: php, arrays, pdf

i am trying yo create dynamic tables on a pdf, but this sentence is not working and i have no idea why:

```
function celda($txt1,$txt2){    
   print_r($txt2);  
   $this->Cell(60,9,$txt1,1,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(60,9,$txt2,1,0,'C');
}   

  $nombre = $p['autor'];    
  $this->celda("Autor",$nombre);
```

the $p variable is and asociative array.

the $txt2 string is not being recognized, it just does not print nothing on the pdf but, the print_r($txt2) teste give me the wanted string. 
if i dont make the asignations and put any other string "like this" it does work.

(i already try this with out the print_r)

actually, none of the functions that print strings on the pdf works with this kind of asignation.

Comment: if you replace **$this->Cell(60,9,$txt2,1,0,'C');** with **$this->Cell(60, 9, ($txt2 ? $txt2 : 'txt2 is empty'), 1, 0, 'C');** what does it display ?

Comment: Then $txt2 is empty. The problem is probably elsewehere in your code. How do you populate your **$p** array? Check what is stored in it.